# With two NIC cards, in Linux (Debian), how do I keep the NICs from getting the same ip address?

Tags: linux, networking, debian

I am using Debian 7 (wheezy).

I have two physical NICs.

I have used ifconfig and gnome-nettool to try and solve this.

When I look at the device tool I see eth0 and eth1 (and the loopback).  eth0 works great.  eth1 gets the same ip address as eth0 no matter how many times I change it (eth1).

They are both on the same subnet and have the same gateway.

example:
`eth0` is 192.168.1.2
`eth1` is supposed to be 192.168.1.3, but eth1 always ends up with 1.2

From terminal I have used:

```
ifconfig eth1 192.168.1.3 gateway 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.1.0
```

no errors.  I also tried to associate a given connection with a specific MAC, but it did not help.

When I look at network connections, wired, I see the first network IP I added "Wired0."  The second is "Wired1."  They both have two different IP Addresses, but the Wired1 never is associated with eth1.

How can I have two NICs on one machine with different IP addresses, same subnet, same gateway?

Comment: can you show your `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

Comment: why do you need two interfaces in one broadcast domain in the first place ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are using network manager in a scenario where you shouldn't. You must dcide whether you use manual IP config or network-manager.

When using manual configuration, then your ifconfig command solves it after disabling network-manager.

If you want to use network-manager, you have to add two Wired connections and limit them to the respective interface. This is possible in the configuration dialog of the connection.

Keep in mind that, no matter which way you choose, what you want to achiev is broken by design and will not work properly in any way. Having two interfaces in the same broadcast domain is a bad idea and never needed. If you need more bandwidth, use etherbonding. If you need a second IP address, use a second address on the one interface.